# When I successfully sign in, redirection should be back to where i left

Tags: login, magento-2.1.9

Currently, our system kind of acts weird.

Steps:

1. I selected cart as guest user
2. Then prior to checking out I signed in
3. Then I input my sign in details
4. Once I successfully signed in, i get redirected to account dashboard.

Is this the normal Magento process?  If not, how do we setup the system so that when I successfully sign in, I get redirected back to where I was prior signing in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't customized anything then this is manageable from  Store -> Configuration -> Customer -> Login Option

[image]

If it is set to Yes then whenever customer will login it will redirect you to dashboard